# MySQL ORDER BY causing extreme slow down with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, left-join, sql-order-by

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.MessageID, OD.Destination 
FROM OutboundMessages AS O LEFT JOIN 
     OutboundMessagesDetails AS OD 
     ON OD.MessageID=O.MessageID
WHERE O.UserID = 18097 AND
      O.Status IS NOT NULL AND
      O.Status <> 'Deleted' 
ORDER BY O.ScheduleDate DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

It takes around 50 seconds to complete. Here is the explain:

```
id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys           key             key_len     ref                         rows    filtered    Extra   
1   SIMPLE          O       NULL        index   PRIMARY,UserSchedule    UserSchedule    4           NULL                        15055   0.08        Using where; Using temporary
1   SIMPLE          OD      NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY                 PRIMARY         8           NMV2_Messaging.O.MessageID  1       100.00      Using index; Distinct
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` clause is on a field in the first table (`OutboundMessages AS O`)

If I remove the `ORDER BY` or the `LEFT JOIN` it takes 0.00035 seconds to complete.

Why is there such a slow down? Presumably it's because MySQL is `LEFT JOINing` every row before doing the `ORDER BY`. If this is correct, is there a way I can prevent this and have MySQL do the `LEFT JOIN` after filtering, limiting and ordering?

Comment: Please make sure that joining table fields having same datatype. I mean OutboundMessagesDetails.MessageID and OutboundMessages.MessageID must be same data type in order to run quick.

Comment: What indexes (and keys) do you have on those tables?

Comment: @LokeshKumarGaurav - the data types are the same.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel - Primary Key is MessageID, Index is on (UserID, ScheduleDate) (amongst others, but that is the only relevant index here)

Comment: If `MessageID` is PK in both tables (one-to-one relation), then you don't need `DISTINCT`, since no duplicates are possible with your query. However - Even if the engine will need to sort 15K rows twice (Once for DISTINCT and once for ORDER BY), it shouldn't take 50 seconds.

Comment: The actual query is built by the system and if the user is filtering on tags, it then additionally has a `LEFT JOIN` to the tags table, which is many-to-many. Interestingly, `DISTINCT` with no `ORDER BY` is fast and so is `ORDER BY` without `DISTINCT`, but together they kill performance!

Comment: So you need to somehow get rid of `DISTINCT`. But I can't tell you how, if I don't see the real query. One way would be to use a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

In order to actually read only 25 rows (see `LIMIT 25`), the `INDEX` needs to get past the `ORDER BY`.

For the `INDEX` to get past the `ORDER BY`, the index needs to end with the columns in the `ORDER BY` (`ScheduleDate`, in your case; there are other criteria, but they are met).  *And* you need to get completely through the `WHERE` clause.

To get *completely* through the `WHERE` clause, *all* the `AND'd` clauses need to be `column = constant`.  `<>` won't do.  `IS NOT NULL` won't do.  A range (not present in your case) won't do *unless* it is the same as the `ORDER BY`.

So, it is impossible.

And anyway, the `DISTINCT` (or a `GROUP BY`) means that it must de-dup before counting off the 25 rows.

But is the `DISTINCT` really needed?  Well, can there be multiple copies of the *same* `Destination` for a given `MessageID`?  If not, does `DISTINCT` do anything for you?

And why have `LEFT`?  That implies that the `Destination` is optional.

Here's another formulation; it may or may not be better:

```
SELECT  O.MessageID, 
    (   SELECT  Destination
            FROM  OutboundMessagesDetails
            WHERE  MessiageID = O.MessageID 
    ) AS Destination
    FROM  OutboundMessages AS O
    WHERE  O.UserID = 18097
      AND  O.Status IS NOT NULL
      AND  O.Status <> 'Deleted'
    ORDER BY  O.ScheduleDate DESC
    LIMIT  0, 25
```

Note:  The inner `SELECT` *may* need `DISTINCT`.

And you need

```
INDEX(UserID,    -- first
      ScheduleDate, -- second
      Status, MessageID)  -- (either order) to make it "covering"
```

Oh, What are the possible values for `Status`?  If there is only one other choice, the replace *both* clauses with `AND O.Status = 'Valid'`.  Now you can use this to get all the way thru!

```
INDEX(UserID, Status, ScheduleDate, MessageID)
```

Note that this is not the same as my previous recommendation.

Note: `NULL` is not equal to anything, not even `NULL`.

And, yes, the other table needs `INDEX(MessageID, Destination)` (unless it has `PRIMARY KEY(MesssageID)` and is InnoDB).

Comment: For the other table index, what if it had 30 columns and I was selecting 29 of them, instead of just destination? Would I need an index across all 29?  MessageID is the primary key in both tables and they are InnoDB, so I guess it doesn't apply, but I am curious :)

Comment: @BenHolness - No.  If there are more than a couple of columns being fetched, don't bother having any extra ones.  The does not get the benefit of "covering", but still gets other benefits.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.MessageID, OD.Destination 
FROM OutboundMessages O LEFT JOIN 
     OutboundMessagesDetails OD 
     ON OD.MessageID = O.MessageID
WHERE O.UserID = 18097 AND
      O.Status IS NOT NULL AND
      O.Status <> 'Deleted' 
ORDER BY O.ScheduleDate DESC
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

You want indexes on `OutboundMessages(UserID, Status, MessageId, Scheduledate)` and `OutboundMessagesDetails(MessageID, Destination)`.

The `SELECT DISTINCT` is also going to slow the query down.  If it is not needed, then remove it.

I want to note that your query sort of doesn't make sense, because you have `SELECT DISTINCT` and the query then orders by a column not in the `SELECT`.  Most databases would reject this.  MySQL allows it.  In this particular case, it is reasonable, because the `DISTINCT` is on (presumably) the primary key in the same table.

Comment: The query doesn't make sense mostly because I trimmed out a lot of stuff from the original query to simplify it for the purpose of asking this question and missed that inconsitency. You can consider `ScheduleDate` to be one of the columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you suggest an index on OutboundMessagesDetails(MessageID, Destination)? It is only being selected,  not filtered on or ordered by.

Comment: @BenHolness . . . For the `JOIN` and `SELECT` column.

Comment: I would be interested to know how it makes a performance difference, I thought indexing was really only relevant to fields that are part of a `JOIN` clause, are part of the `WHERE` conditions, or are part of an `ORDER BY` section. I don't understand how it helps here, where the field in question (Destination) is only being `SELECTed`

Comment: @BenHolness - I think Gordon was making [_Covering Indexes_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#_covering_indexes)